# php session is not working on subdomains

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

My session code was working before, however now all of a sudden it is not working, and also, if I call `set_session.php` from `www.domain.com`, then I call `test_session.php` from `domain.com`, it produces nothing. No session variable is set, and it only produces output if I call `test_session.php` from `www.domain.com`. When I call `set_session` from `domain.com` or `www.domain.com`, calling `test_session.php` from other subdomains(i.e `sub.domain.com`), the session also does not show up. Even though I already used `session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com')`. What is the correct way to do this ?

set_session.php

```
<?php
session_name('mysession');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com');
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = 'Session is set';
echo $_SESSION['test'];
?>
```

test_session.php

```
<?php
session_name('mysession');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com');
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['test'];
?>
```

All answers and suggestions are greatly welcomed and appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A cookie lifetime of `0` might be a bit too short:

```
session_set_cookie_params(30*60, '/', '.domain.com');
```

**EDIT**

additionally, I would check whether a cookie named `mysession` is actually set in the browser.

Furthermore, check your logs: one of the reasons might be that the session store (which usually is file based) isn't writable or disk is full i.e.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime
From what I read here, if you set 0, The value 0 means "until the browser is closed." Defaults to 0.

Comment: @Charas yes, right, but I have also had several "strange encounters" with 5.3 session handling :/